# Error Sending Dynamic values to the mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a attendence form but the from contain the values which are calling from another mysql table 
the form which i want to send is

```
<?php require_once('Connections/db.php'); ?>
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,Name,Roll_No FROM examination_creg WHERE attendence='1'");

echo "<form  method=POST action=send.php >";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Roll_No</th>
<th>Present</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=std_name value=".$row['Name']." readonly=readonly     />" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=std_roll value=".$row['Roll_No']." readonly=readonly />" . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . "<Select name=present>
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>" . "</td>";


  echo "</tr>";

  }
echo "</table>";
   echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=send value=Submit />" . "</td>";
echo "</form>";


?>
```

the the file send.php is

```
<?php 
$name=$_POST['std_name'];
$roll=$_POST['std_roll'];
$present=$_POST['present'];
echo $name;
echo $roll;
echo $present;



?>
```

i just print these values here to know the problem

in first code the values name , roll no came from the mysql table where id=1
when i send the form it only print the single value which is on the last field ???
Remaining data is not printed here so how the data will be store in the data base if the variables does not contain it so
please help me
as early as possible

Comment: it will print only the last row of data

Comment: First, you should wrap your attribute values in quotes ie: type='text'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason why your send.php is only receiving one value is because it's coming from your one and only writable field while your first two text fields have the attribute:

```
readonly=readonly
```

Try removing that attribute.

Comment: i have removed readonly='readonly' but the problem is still there ??

Comment: Is your table empty or are you not returning any results from your query?

Comment: my field contains the data which is called from the form examination_creg where attendence=1
so that all the students who has attendence=1 are shown in this form 
so that the form contain multiple values.

Comment: But is the table that you're trying to query empty?  If you manually execute that query, does it return results?

Comment: when i send the data to the database it only save the last row of the form ....only last row's name ,roll no etc

Comment: Send data via the form you have above or manually ie an INSERT statement?

Comment: i have not written the INSERT STATEMENT because when the variable print only one value so its mean that the variable only contain 1 value i think there is an error in the form page or in the send page i think i should need to apply foreach() or for or while loop at some where ?

Comment: If you open a SQL browser or open mysql in the console and execute that query, what does it return?

Comment: it return only last one row's data

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.